# Passing parameters for TABLE_QUERY in Google Cloud Datalab iPython notebook

Tags: sql, ipython, parameter-passing, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I'm still quite new to the Google Cloud Datalab and have some troubles executing parameterized queries.

I followed the example for passing query parameters from [Datalab tutorial](https://main-dot-datalab-dot-o7datalab.appspot.com/notebooks/datalab/tutorials/BigQuery/SQL%20Parameters.ipynb) and tried to apply it on the following query:

```
%sql
SELECT user_id, localTime, event
FROM (SELECT user_id, DATE_ADD(date, timezoneOffset, "SECOND") AS localTime, event
  FROM (TABLE_QUERY([my_project:my_dataset:user_events], 
       'table_id CONTAINS "user_events_0" 
       AND RIGHT(table_id, 8) BETWEEN "20160401" AND "20160408"'))
  WHERE 
  user_id IS NOT NULL AND
  timezoneOffset IS NOT NULL AND
  event IS NOT NULL)
WHERE 
  user_id IN (SELECT id FROM [my_project:my_dataset.topUsers])
ORDER BY user_id, localTime
```

I want to iterate over all *user_events* tables, with indexes 0,1,2,3 ... For that purpose, I'd like to pass the parameter for the TABLE_QUERY and query every table in one iteration of a loop - not all of the tables at the same time. (Because I need to order user records within each table; the resources are exceeded when executing a query over all *user_events* tables at once)

1.) I defined a new query (`%%sql --module topUserEvents` etc.) and replaced the following part from the query above:

```
 FROM (TABLE_QUERY([my_project:my_dataset:user_events], 
      'table_id CONTAINS "user_events_0" 
       AND RIGHT(table_id, 8) BETWEEN "20160401" AND "20160408"'))
```

with:

```
  FROM (TABLE_QUERY([my_project:my_dataset:user_events], 
       'table_id CONTAINS "user_events_'+$tableNr+ 
       '" AND RIGHT(table_id, 8) BETWEEN "20160401" AND "20160408"'))
```

Executed the query, passing table number as a string - didn't work:

```
invalidQuery: Expected a string literal for TABLE_QUERY clause
```

2.) I also tried passing the whole string, replacing part of the original query with:

```
  FROM (TABLE_QUERY([my_project:my_dataset:user_events], $tableString))
```

Executed the query, passing the whole string, returned Big Query Exception:

```
invalidQuery: Error preparing subsidiary query:
com.google.cloud.helix.server.bqsql.common.BigQueryException:
Encountered " "CONTAINS" "CONTAINS "" at line 1, column 94.
Was expecting:
")" ...
```

---

Does anyone know **how to pass (a part of) a string for TABLE_QUERY parameter**, such as in the case above?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following?

**Define module 'test1':**

```
%%sql --module test1
SELECT count(*)
FROM TABLE_QUERY(publicdata:samples, 
  'MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(creation_time) < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, $period)')
```

**Run query:**

```
period = 'DAY'
bq.Query(test1, period = period).sample()
```

---

**Define module 'test2':**

```
%sql --module test2
SELECT user_id, localTime, event
FROM (SELECT user_id, DATE_ADD(date, timezoneOffset, "SECOND") AS localTime, event
  FROM (TABLE_QUERY([my_project:my_dataset:user_events], 
       'table_id CONTAINS $events_table_num 
       AND RIGHT(table_id, 8) BETWEEN "20160401" AND "20160408"'))
  WHERE 
  user_id IS NOT NULL AND
  timezoneOffset IS NOT NULL AND
  event IS NOT NULL)
WHERE 
  user_id IN (SELECT id FROM [my_project:my_dataset.topUsers])
ORDER BY user_id, localTime
```

**Run query:**

```
events_table_num = 'user_events_0'
bq.Query(test2,events_table_num = events_table_num).sample()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried similar solution too, but wasn't working because I used the quotes around the passed argument; `FROM (TABLE_QUERY([my_project:my_dataset:user_events], 
       'table_id CONTAINS "$events_table_num" 
       AND RIGHT(table_id, 8) BETWEEN "20160401" AND "20160408"'))` That made sense to me, but for some reason the quotes need to be omitted to work. 

Thanks again :)